# Laravel: API not found in production environment

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, axios

I have created an API called "getservicedata" which returns data to be used in Vue.js component.The problem is I get a 404 status code on my production enviroment, which means the file cannot be found. Locally, this is not an issue, only on the production environment.

api.php file:

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:sanctum'], function(){
    // Create new API estimate
    Route::apiResource('estimate', EstimateController::class);
    // Get Service Data
    Route::get('/services/getservicedata', [ServiceController::class, 'getServiceData']);
    // Create new API Service
    Route::apiResource('services', ServiceController::class);

});
```

ServiceController file:

```
    public function getServiceData()
    {
        $services = Service::with('vendor')->get();

        return $services;
    }
```

Vue.js component:

```
   methods: {
        loadServices: function(){
            axios.get('/api/services/getservicedata')
            .then(response => {
                this.services = response.data;
            })
            .catch(function(error){
                console.log(error);
            });
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Please clear the route cache on the production. Still, you face the issue then check the route list of laravel with the below command and see route exists with which URL.

```
php artisan route:list
```

Thanks!